# Views Exposed Filters loading javascript each time

Tags: 7, ajax, javascript, views

I have an exposed filter with ajax enabled in a views. Every time I click different filter option it reloads the javascript. Is this the normal behavior or known issues with views 3? 
Is there any way to prevent reloading entire javascript?

Thank

Comment: Did you mean your js doesn`t work after ajax call?

Comment: No js is working fine but it is reloading every time I click the filter option. I don't see the usage of ajax if entire page reloads.